# emacsでEclipseの「実行の構成」の機能と同じようなことはできないのでしょうか？

Tags: emacs

EclipseやIntelliJにはサーバー起動やテスト実行等のコマンドを設定し、
それに名前をつけて保存し、ドロップダウンから選択して実行できる機能があるのですが、
Emacsにはそれに相当する機能はあったりしますでしょうか？

2016-04-20 追記

こんな感じの設定を入れることでanythingに表示できるようになりました。

~/.emacs.d/init.el

```
;; .emacs.d/init.el
(require 'f)

;; 指定のファイル内に定義された関数名をリストで取得
(defun list-defined-functions-in-file (file)
  (-map 'cadr (s-match-strings-all "defun \\(exec-.*?\\) "
                                   (f-read file))))

;; ~/.emacs.d/init.d/99_run_configuration.elの関数一覧を取ってくる
(setq run-congiguration-candidates (list-defined-functions-in-file "~/.emacs.d/init.d/99_run_configuration.el"))

;; anythingの情報源として99_run_configuration.elの関数の一覧を定義
(defvar anything-c-source-run-configuration
  '((name . "Run configuration")
    (candidates . (lambda () run-congiguration-candidates))
    (type . command)))

(defun my-anything ()
  (interactive)
  (anything-other-buffer
   '(anything-c-source-buffers-list
     anything-c-source-run-configuration ;; ここで上記の情報源を追加
     anything-c-source-recentf
     anything-c-source-files-in-current-dir+)
   "*anything*"))
```

~/.emacs.d/init.d/99_run_configuration

```
;; このファイルに実行したいコマンドを追加していく
(defun exec-lein-ring-server ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command "cd ~/clojure_projects/sample_project; lein ring server"))

(defun exec-lein-deps ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command "cd ~/clojure_projects/sample_project; lein deps"))
```

[image: Run Configurationが追加した部分です]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「実行の構成」でやりたいことは何でしょうか。
やりたいことが、特定のコマンドへの名前付け実行ならば、

1. emacs は、シェルを実行できます。
2. シェルを実行する操作を、関数定義して、それを `M-x` で呼び出すことができます。

ことでもって、一応は実現できますが、これと比較して足りていないと思う機能がありますか？あるとしたら、どのような場合にその機能が欲しいと思っていますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
やりたいことは「特定コマンドを名前をつけて保存し呼び出す」
ということなのでこれでいけそうな気がします。
欲を言えばanythingやhelmの候補一覧に出てきてくれるとベストなのですが、そう言ったことはできますでしょうか？

Comment: @cyubachi helm は、 M-x の関数すべてに対しては補完が効いていると理解していますが、今やろうとしている、名前の付けたコマンドの実行だけを補完したい、ということですか？

Comment: > 今やろうとしている、名前の付けたコマンドの実行だけを補完したい、ということですか？  
  
ああ、その通りです。
すみません、ちょっと言葉が足りてませんでしたね。

Comment: それだったら、 helm を少しハックすると、何かしらできそうですね。パッとはでてきませんが…

Comment: ちょっと不格好ですが、↑の追記に書いたように設定を入れるとうまく行きました。ありがとうございました。m(_ _)m